# How can I remove giving args in the terminal and add my own args inside the argparse

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, argparse, opencv3.0

I want to create a directory of the input taken from my python program and give that as an argument to an argParser which is in the same code.

I just basically want to make a directory of the file name the user enter and run so that i can make a dataset of his images into that specified folder.

```py
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os

intr=input("Hello Intruder enter Your name")
print(intr)
dirpath=os.path.join('./dataset',intr)
os.mkdir(dirpath)
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-c", "--cascade", required=True,
    help = "path to where the face cascade resides")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output","dataset/unknown", required=True,
    help="path to output directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(args["cascade"])
```

What I'm getting:

```
(cv) ASKV:opencv-face-recognition askvyas$ python build_face_dataset.py --cascade haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml --output dataset/unknown
Hello Intruder enter Your namekiu
kiu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_face_dataset.py", line 18, in <module>
    help="path to output directory")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1320, in add_argument
    kwargs = self._get_optional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1451, in _get_optional_kwargs
    raise ValueError(msg % args)
ValueError: invalid option string 'dataset/unknown': must start with a character '-'
```

Comment: Problem in second `add_argument` call. If you want to set default value, a keyword argument required `default = "dataset/unknown"`.

Comment: Can i add a newly made directory (using os in the same program)?

Comment: Do you understand why `"dataset/unknown"` is not a valid parameter?

Comment: Not that it contributes to your error, but usually `parse_args()` is used first, upon starting the script.  Any user interaction, using `input()`, comes later.  That is, the first task is to parse the values provided on the command line.  In fact if the parser is complete enough, your user shouldn't have to provide any further information interactively.  The `name` can be provided on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I do it:
Build a class, then if the file is called from bash python myfile.py, update the class with the argparser. If the command is called from another file, this skips the argparse part.

example ( caveat, I typed this without running it so it may contain a typo, but in essence it works)

```py
class ARGS:
    def __init__(self, some_str_arg="this", some_float_arg=0.7, some_int_arg=12):
        self.some_str_arg = some_str_arg
        self.some_float_arg = some_float_arg
        self.some_int_arg = some_int_arg
    def set_from_parser(self):
        # here you could get fancier and add arguments parsing the class dict, but for simplicity I duplicate tehm
        import argparse
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Some Parser")
        parse.add_argument('--some_str_arg', default=self.some_str_arg, type=str, help='my string arg')
        parse.add_argument('--some_float_arg', default=self.some_float_arg, type=float, help='my foat arg')
        parse.add_argument('--some_int_arg', default=self.some_int_arg, type=int, help='my string arg')

        args = parser.parse_args()
        for _a in args.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[_a] = args.__dict__[_a]

def some_fun(A=None, **kwargs):
    # this you can call from python as
    # >>> some_fun(some_str_arg="cogito ergo sum", some_float_arg=1.618, some_int_arg=42)
    # or from bash as
    # $ python myfun.py --some_str_arg really --some_float_arg 3.14 --some_int_arg 0
    if A is None:
        A = ARGS()
        for kw in kwargs:
            if kw in A.__dict__:
                A.__dict__[kw] = kwargs[kw]
    ... do something

if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = ARGS()
    A.set_from_parser()
    some_fun(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make `--output` argument as "not required", and set `dirpath` as default value:

```
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", default=dirpath, help="path to output directory")
```